# How can i fix my program? Pygame keeps not working

Tags: pygame

I am making a game, but it doesn't work. I am new to pygame, so I think I did somenthing stupid in my code. (It opens the pygame window, but just doesn't work.)

the code in question:

```
from pygame import image
import time
import os
import subprocess
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
from pygame import mixer
pygame.event.pump
def image(imagename):
    img = pygame.image.load(imagename)
    black = (0, 0 ,0 )
    w = 1251
    h = 584
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
    screen.fill((black))
    running = 1
    while running:
        screen.fill((black))
        screen.blit(img,(0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
def backstory():
    pygame.init;
    image(imagename='backtory.')
    time.sleep(25)    
def title():
    pygame.init()
    image(imagename='title_screen.jpg')
    time.sleep(3)
    backstory()
title()
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        None
```

Comment: can you include more description of what happens when you open the window, rather than just doesn't work?

Comment: Please read the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and describe your goals, the problems and what you've tried to fix them. Also, provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

"Just doesn't work" doesn't tell us much, but looking at the code I think I got what you had intended to do. Here's some fixed code, with the wrong lines commented out. Make sure you fix the image file name in `image(imagename='backtory.')` too.

```
from pygame import image
import time
import os
import subprocess
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
from pygame import mixer
pygame.event.pump
def image(imagename):
    img = pygame.image.load(imagename)
    black = (0, 0 ,0 )
    w = 1251
    h = 584
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
    screen.fill((black))
    #running = 1
    #while running:
    #    screen.fill((black))
    screen.blit(img,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
def backstory():
    # pygame.init;
    image(imagename='backstory.jpg')
    time.sleep(25)    
def title():
    pygame.init()
    image(imagename='title_screen.jpg')
    time.sleep(3)
    backstory()

title()
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        None
```